# GitHub multiple environments

Tags: github, github-actions, cicd

As I am new to GitHub so I trying to understand how to build a CI/CD pipeline correctly.

The problem that I have is in our company I have 3 environments: dev, test and live.

What I need: to build artifact (docker image) with build number as a tag and deploy it to all three environments.

How I should do that? I have one build workflow that produces an image and 3 deploy workflows in which I use environment like:

```
environment:
  name: DEV
```

How I can use it if I have to deploy not the latest build (e.g. build nr 10) but build nr 3 for example.

Comment: How do you host your app? k8s or something else?

Comment: I use on-prem k8s.

Comment: And so far how do deploy there apps? Helm charts?

Comment: I do not use Helm.
I have 2 options. 
Option 1: to use one workflow and 2 separate jobs: build and deploy. Problem is that I cannot execute only deploy if I need that (for redeploy purpose), I need to execute full workflow and it makes another build.. not a good solution. I need to use already existing build.

Option 2: to use 2 separate workflows, then I can execute deploy separately, but in this case how I specify that I want to deploy not the latest build but e.g. previous.

Comment: It sounds like you could make use of the [`workflow_dispatch`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_dispatch) event in your deploy workflows. You may configure the build number that you want to specify via its `inputs` with `latest` as the default.

Comment: how I can use it as imputs?